# Add getChildAt() to custom tablerow class

Tags: android, tablerow

I've made a `TableRow` class and added my own methods to it. In the `TableRow` is a `EditText` where i want to retreive values from. I thought about using the `getChildAt()` for finding the right `EditText` in the right `TableRow`. But because i made my own `TableRow` class i can't use the `getChildAt()` wich is in the original `TableRow` class or parents of it.

So how can i get the `EditText` values from the tablerows? Create my own getChildAt method?(if so, how?) or is there a different way?

Comment: If possible use setTag method for each EditText and when required you can retrieve particular EditText using that tag.

Comment: @Crimson i am not totally clear with your question but i try.

Comment: @Swetank thanks I used the setTag for each EditText and i retreived the EditText with the getTag at the particular row.

Answer (score 0):

Example-

```
EditText editEmail, editPass;
String name = "", pass = "";
editEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail); 
editPass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPass); 
name = editEmail.getText().toString();
pass = editPass.getText().toString();
```

you can try this. the values now in string variable and you can use these variables wherever you want.

Comment: Yes it's solved. The textfields in the tablerows assign their value to the row they're in.

Answer (score 0):

**Whenever you create dynamic view** you can assign an id to that view as

```
final int  ID=1001;
EditText et=new EditText(this);
et.setId(ID);
```

and get the view using

```
findviewbyid(ID) ;
```

**If you are using xml**

```
 android:id="@+id/ed1"
```

In Activity

```
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
```